# Cannot mount SD card

Tags: mount, sd-card

I have Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit and I have used a new 16GB SD card for a couple of weeks that suddenly is not recognizable anymore. When doing `sudo fdisk -l` and  then `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1/ /media/sdcard/` it appears

> mount: special device /dev/mmcblk0p1/ does not exist (a path prefix is not a directory)

Any suggestions on what the problem could be?

Cheers

Comment: Sure, I agree. The number 422 is not divisible by 8. So what is your question?

Comment: Please don't use images, to document text. They don't scale well with the fontsize, they aren't indexable, you can't copy parts of it to feed searchengines or to take parts to test yourself. And it is very easy in Linux to copy-paste a whole page, even more or just parts, by marking and middle mouse click in the target field.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of image to document text.

Comment: Try without the trailing slashes in the mount command, `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/sdcard` ; Particularly the trailing slash in the device specification might be problematic.

Comment: "Try without the trailing slashes in the mount command, sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/sdcard ; Particularly the trailing slash in the device specification might be problematic. –" Thanks! That was the problem! It works now.

Comment: You are welcome and thanks for letting us know what works for you :-)